# Want a tool to visualize XAML hierarchy, tried XAMLPadX had problems

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like a tool to visualize the Visual Hierarchy of a XAML file - just an outline of what elements are within what other elements.

I downloaded XAMLPadX 4.0 and opened a GridSplitter example file:

```
<Window x:Class="GridsplitterSample.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="GridSplitter Sample" Height="400" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="4" Background="Yellow"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 4 0" Background="LightGray">Text Block</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGreen">Text Block 2</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

. . .  This example runs and builds fine in Visual Studio 2010 but in XAMLPadX it showed nothing on the main screen and in the Visual Tree window it only expanded as far as the outer Grid element and there was no "+" to expand that any farther to show the inner Grids, TextBlocks or GridSplitter.

XamlPadX came with sample files so I loaded "Red Dragon".   It displayed the XAML and a red dragon on the main screen.   But now I can't get RID of the red dragon!   No matter what else I load that's all I see in the main window and Visual Tree, even though different XAML is loaded in the XAML window.  Red Dragon seems to have broken the tool and resrating it seems to make no difference.

So am I doing something wrong or is there a better tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't already familiar than there's no other tool I know of that is nearly as handy as [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) and I know normally it's frowned upon to provide answers that are only a couple sentences. However for working with XAML in WPF/SL Expression Blend is excellent once you get used to it. The Objects / Timeline and visual Properties etc. make dev so much more efficient! If you can't tell, I'm a big fan.

Or if you haven't already done so you can enable the [Document Outline window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in Visual Studio and it also helps quite a bit with visualizing the structure. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm only looking for a tool to show the element hierarchy.   Expression Blend is a very expensive tool that does a lot more than I need here.   But I didn't know about Document Outline and it seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad you got your remedy.

Answer (score 1):

Could use [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf).  Will attach to any compatible .NET managed app, I think it might even support some Silverlight apps.  CTRL+Shift+Mouseover to highlight areas and expose them in the document hierarchy.